# Automatically test formats in Rails functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, binding, functional-testing

I'd like to make each of my functional tests automatically test various formats. It seems like the way to achieve this is to wrap up the 'test' method in my own class method:

```
def self.test_all_formats(name)
  [ "xml", "json" ].each do |fmt|
    test "#{name} #{fmt}" do
      yield(format)
    end
  end
end

test_all_formats "index" do |fmt|
  get :index, { :format => fmt }
  assert_response :ok
end
```

Unfortunately, each test results in the following error raised:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for AccountsControllerTest:Class.

Although execution of the block is deferred until execution of the test, it's trying to run the block in the context of the class rather than instance.

Is there a way to achieve this automated testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
class << self
  def test_all_formats(name, &block)
    [ "xml", "json" ].each do |fmt|
      test "#{name} #{fmt}" do
        instance_exec fmt, &block
      end
    end
  end
end

test_all_formats "index" do |fmt|
  get :index, { :format => fmt }
  assert_response :ok
end
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but you had also posted an earlier solution that might be preferable to some. I'll post it as another answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

This code was originally provided as Chris Oei's solution, and may be preferable if you dislike using instance_exec:

```
class << self
   def test_formats(name, &block)
    define_method "fmt_#{name}", &block
      [ "xml", "json" ].each do |fmt|
        test "#{name} #{fmt}" do
          send "fmt_#{name}", fmt
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```